# how to open multiple files in CtrlP split in a new window

Tags: ctrlp

Assume I have a set of related files (say .C implementation file and .h header file). I would like to open both of these in a new window on search but they should be split(horizontally/vertically) so that I can view them together. What is the easiest way to do this in CtrlP ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `c-z` to select the files and then `c-o` to open them.

From the README: https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim#basic-usage

Comment: Note that the `g:ctrlp_open_multiple_files` option determines what happens when you press c-o.  It defaults to vertical splits, but can be set to open horizontal splits or tabs as well.